# Weird bug in Jquery? Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my jquery code:

```
$("input").val().split("\").pop().split(".")[0];
```

In the console I'm getting a red squiggly line under this like of code, starting from the dot inside the second split, to the end of the line of code.

I have no idea why this is happening, but when I remove the

```
.split(".")[0]
```

It still returns the same error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: look at the code highlighting ... you need \\ instead of \ in the split, because \ is treated specially - see [escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation)

Answer (score 5):

You're receiving that error because the `\` character is escaping the `"` next to it so the whole statement is being misunderstood. See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp, section **Special Characters** for clarification.

In order to split using the character `\` as separator you should write:

`$("input").val().split("\\").pop().split(".")[0];`

(Note the double `\` in the string passed as first `split` parameter)